# I want to fix flex bison error "invalid token"

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

```
expr JG term    {$$=MakeOPTree(JG, $1, $3);} //JG is ">"
```

Node * MakeOPTree(int op, Node* operand1, Node* operand2)
{

```
Node * newnode;
newnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof (Node));
newnode->token = op;
newnode->tokenval = op;
newnode->son = operand1;
newnode->brother = NULL;
operand1->brother = operand2;
return newnode;
```

}

Node * MakeNode(int token, int operand)
{

```
Node * newnode;
newnode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof (Node));
newnode->token = token;
newnode->tokenval = operand; 
newnode->son = newnode->brother = NULL;
return newnode;
```

}

Node * MakeListTree(Node* operand1, Node* operand2)
{

```
Node * newnode;
Node * node;

if (operand1 == NULL){
    newnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof (Node));
    newnode->token = newnode-> tokenval = STMTLIST;
    newnode->son = operand2;
    newnode->brother = NULL;
    return newnode;
    }
else {
    node = operand1->son;
    while (node->brother != NULL) node = node->brother;
    node->brother = operand2;
    return operand1;
    }
```

}

I'm using this AST but I can't fix this error
cmd says "invalid token > "

What can I do?

Comment: That error is probably being produced by your scanner, not by your parser. Certainly, nothing in the code you pasted shows that message, and it is not generated automatically by either flex or bison. Please read [ask] for some advice on how to ask good questions, and particularly the section on creating a [mre]. The more detailed your question, the easier it is to answer, making it more likely that you will get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! but It doesn't work.... Anyway, thank for your answer

Comment: It wasn't an answer: it was a suggestion for how to ask a better question. I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't work"; all I can say is that the message you ask about is produced by your code but not by the code you present, so it is impossible to help you more until you help yourself by improving your question.

Comment: That's what you meant.... It's my firsrt question and use stackoverflow for the first time. so I had no idea. I'll keep that in mind next time. Thanks advice! And have a good day!